# Scandir subfolder issue, looping through folders and files into separate arrays

Tags: php, content-management-system, scandir

building a site for a client who wants to be able to just upload files to their server (with specific naming) and have them parsed for the site content. I got it working great for the first initial folder but I am having a hard time exporting the subfolder files are their own array. Here is the code:

```
    $files = scandir(getcwd());
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if(is_file($file)) {
            if ($file == 'description.txt') {
                // php less than or equal 5
                $description = file_get_contents('./description.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
            }
            if ($file == 'subtitle.txt') {
                // php less than or equal 5
                $subtitle = file_get_contents('./subtitle.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
            }
            if ($file == 'item.png') {
                $mainImage = 'item.png';
            }
            if ($file == 'item.jpg') {
                $mainImage = 'item.jpg';
            }
        } elseif (is_dir($file)) {
            $subFiles = scandir($file);
            foreach ($subFiles as $file2) {
                echo $file2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is that $file2 is including the all of the files from the parent directory instead of just the items from the subfolder. If I echo out $files before the foreach it will also include the subfolder and subfolder files which isnt preferable but doesn't really get in the way of what I want to do either. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scandir also returns "." and ".." which are also dirs so the else part of you code         if(is_file($file)) { is also being executed.  check and skip "." and ".." while looping which will solve the problem

```
$files = scandir(getcwd());
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if(is_file($file)) {
        if ($file == 'description.txt') {
            // php less than or equal 5
            $description = file_get_contents('./description.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        }
        if ($file == 'subtitle.txt') {
            // php less than or equal 5
            $subtitle = file_get_contents('./subtitle.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        }
        if ($file == 'item.png') {
            $mainImage = 'item.png';
        }
        if ($file == 'item.jpg') {
            $mainImage = 'item.jpg';
        }
    } elseif (is_dir($file)) {
        if($file=="." || $file==".."){
            continue;
        }
        $subFiles = scandir($file);
        foreach ($subFiles as $file2) {
            echo $file2;
        }
    }
}
```